# Problemas con agregar dos condiciones en clausula on en join Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Saludos tengo un problema con agregarle otra clausula de condición a mi left join en linq mi codigo

```
 var concept =(from sol in tabla1
                               join cosol in ctx.tabla2 on sol.ID equals cosol.ID
                               join iden in ctx.tabla3 on cosol.ID equals iden.ID
                               join conc in ctx.tabla4 on iden.ID equals conc.ID
                               join tipConcep in ctx.tabla4 on conc.ID equals tipConcep.ID
                               
                               join conNam in ctx.tabla5 on  iden.ID equals conNam.ID  into nt from conNam in nt.DefaultIfEmpty() 

where sol.numero== solicitud.numero

orderby cosol.FECHA_CREACION descending
select new { tabla1.nombre}).ToList();
```

lo que esta en el codigo esta hasta la primera condicion de la consulta pero necesito al ultimo join agregarle la otra condicion en sql seria asi

```
left join tabla5 as catN on conNam.ID = iden.ID and conNam.ID = cosol.ID
```

ahi esta la linea de left join en sql que tiene dos condiciones , necesito agregar la segunda condicion `and conNam.ID = cosol.ID` en lin q  , porfavor si alguien me puede ayudar.

Comment: Hacer un join sobre dos columnas, o "llave compuesta", según la [documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/formulate-joins-and-cross-product-queries#example-10). Ya probaste `left join tabla5 as catN on new {conNam.ID, conNam.ID } equals new {iden.ID, cosol.ID}` ?

Answer (score 1):

Lo solucione de la siguiente manera por si alguien le ayuda así me quedaría la consulta en linq después de poner el new con los campos me dio un problema de que eran de tipo diferentes y la solucione poniendo nombres y convirtiendo a los id en enteros.

```
var concept =(from sol in tabla1
                               join cosol in ctx.tabla2 on sol.ID equals cosol.ID
                               join iden in ctx.tabla3 on cosol.ID equals iden.ID
                               join conc in ctx.tabla4 on iden.ID equals conc.ID
                               join tipConcep in ctx.tabla4 on conc.ID equals tipConcep.ID
                               
                               join conNam in ctx.tabla5 on new { conceptoId = (int)iden.ID , concepNombre = (int)cosol.ID }  equals new { conceptoId = (int)conNam.ID , concepNombre = conNam.ID}   into nt from conNam in nt.DefaultIfEmpty() 

where sol.numero== solicitud.numero

orderby cosol.FECHA_CREACION descending
select new { tabla1.nombre}).ToList();
```